# Install MySQL 5.5 in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have been downloaded the DEB package of mysql 5.5.23.
Install MySQL by the command as follows:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-5.5.23-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
```

The result said that installed successfully.
But when I type the command:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Or

```
mysql
```

It shows me that "mysql: unrecognized service" or "mysql: command not found".
Besides, I can't find MySQL files in "/usr/include" or "/usr/bin"

Please help me. Thx.

Comment: I've solved the problem. MySQL 5.5.x installed to the /opt directory.

Comment: Are you able to login to your database from another machine ? I installed mysql on ubuntu on virtual box but I can't access the database using the workbench from windows (host OS). I commented the "bind-address" configuration in /etc/mysql/my.cnf but still can't login from windows !

Comment: @rainisic I am facing same problem. How can i start mysql ? It is /opt directory

Answer (score 1):

Because MySQL 5.5.x is not packaged, in repositories only exist 5.1.x
This worked for me:
http://www.rebojo.com/debian-installing-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple command :

sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Comment: Becuase this implies having an internet connection. Which may not be always the case (ex. intranet).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Download URL

`https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.56-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz`

#### Open the terminal and follow along:

- Uninstall any existing version of MySQL

  `sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/ -R`
- Delete the MySQL profile

  `sudo rm /etc/mysql/ -R`
- Automatically uninstall mysql

  `sudo apt-get autoremove mysql* --purge
   sudo apt-get remove apparmor`
- Download version 5.5.51 from MySQL site

  `wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.56-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz`
- Add mysql user group

  `sudo groupadd mysql`
- Add mysql (not the current user) to mysql user group

  `sudo useradd -g mysql mysql`
- Extract it

  `sudo tar -xvf mysql-5.5.56-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz`
- Move it to /usr/local

  `sudo mv mysql-5.5.56-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64 /usr/local/`
- Create mysql folder in /usr/local by moving the untarred folder

  `cd /usr/local
  sudo mv mysql-5.5.49-linux2.6-x86_64 mysql`
- set MySql directory owner and user group

  `cd mysql
  sudo chown -R mysql:mysql *`
- Install the required lib package (works with 5.6 as well)

  `sudo apt-get install libaio1`
- Execute mysql installation script

  `sudo scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql`
- Set mysql directory owner from outside the mysql directory

  `sudo chown -R root .`
- Set data directory owner from inside mysql directory

  `sudo chown -R mysql data`
- Copy the mysql configuration file

  `sudo cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf`
- Start mysql

  `sudo bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
  sudo cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server`
- Set root user password

  `sudo bin/mysqladmin -u root password '[your new password]'`
- Add mysql path to the system

  `sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql`
- Reboot!
- Start mysql server

  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server start`
- Stop mysql server

  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server stop`
- Check status of mysql

  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server status`
- Enable myql on startup

  `sudo update-rc.d -f mysql.server defaults`

*Disable mysql on startup (Optional)

```
`sudo update-rc.d -f mysql.server remove`
```

- REBOOT!
- Now login using below command, start mysql server if it's not running already

  `mysql -u root -p`